# Calling outside functions in inline functions

Tags: c++, function, inline

Say I have the inline function:

```
// equality operator where left operand is a long
inline bool operator==(long num, BigInt const& val) {
    return compare(num, val) == 0;
}
```

where 'compare' is defined in BigInt.h where the inline function is. How can I use compare or can I even use it?

BigInt.h

```
class BigInt {

public:

//code

int BigInt::compare(long num, BigInt const& other) const;

//code

};

// equality operator where left operand is a long
inline bool operator==(long num, BigInt const& val) {
    return compare(num, val) == 0;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you seeing ? Do you get a compile error ? If so then please include any actual error messages in your question.

Comment: It just says compare is undefined.

Comment: Have you tried including BigInt.h?

Comment: What's *compare*? A private member of a class? A static one? A global function? [Continue...]. It's in BigInt.h, so show us that file (correctly cleaned up, of course).

Comment: Compare is public and is implemented in BigInt.cpp, this inline function is in BigInt.h

Comment: it's implemented in the .cpp, but is it also declared in BigInt.h?

Comment: BTW, `inline` has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: The function prototype is just in BigInt.h

Comment: Show us some more code. I'm sure this is an easy one!

Comment: added some bigint.h code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compare` is a member function, you should change call it like

```
// equality operator where left operand is a long
inline bool operator==(long num, BigInt const& val) {
    return val.compare(num, val) == 0;
}
```

And I'm still doubt why `compare` is a member function. If it has nothing to do with the current object it should be just a normal function or static member function.